# Multidimensional arrays with enhanced for loop in java printing to the command line

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm basically extrapolating from a question that was already posted and answered in this forum     that I modified but couldn't print to the command line. It is similar to a problem from my java lesson at college in which we were suppose to use the enhanced for loop on a three dimensional array. I get an error message that is "illegal start of expression" and "not a statement". I almost got it to compile but I'm missing something. I need some help. Here is the code:

```
public class ThreeDimensionalArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][][] array = new int[4][5][6];//initializing array
        int sum = 0;//define sum
        for (int[][] i : array)//start of enhanced for loop
        {
            for (int[] j : i)
                for (int k : j)
                    sum += k;

            System.out.println("Output is " + sum);//output sum
        }//end enhanced for loop
    }//end method main

}//end ThreeDimensionalArray
```

Comment: remove the brackets around the k.

Comment: I removed the brackets around the k. This code is exactly the way my instructor outlined it yesterday in class . According to him the  first for loop is for the 3D, the second for the 2D and the third for the 1D. And sum is assigned to the variable k.

Comment: Your instructor's description is correct.  A 3D array of `int` is best thought of as "an array of arrays of arrays of `int`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The println has to be after all loop.

```
public class ThreeDimensionalArray
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
int[][][] array = new int[4][5][6];//initializing array
int sum=0;//define sum
for(int[][] i: array)//start of enhanced for loop
{
for(int[] j: i)

for(int k:j) 
sum +=[k];



}//end enhanced for loop
  System.out.println("Output is",sum);//output sum
}//end method main

//end ThreeDimensionalArray
}
```

Comment: I just used the printf format specifier and it compiled.But the sum is 0, when I run it, which is the wrong answer. I got to work on the logic some more. Thank everybody for your help and answers.

Comment: @swydell, you're getting 0 because the array is never initialized (filled in with values) in your code.  Since it's `int`s, they default to 0.

Comment: I agree, you need to initiate the arrays content

Comment: Actually the answer 0 is correct. But how  to I initialize the array content. I thought I had already done that with the indicies 4,5,6. I'm a bit confused now. This is a three dimensional array, right? Now what for loop initializes the rows, and what for loop initializes the columns?

Comment: The 4,5, and 6 just tell it how *big* the arrays need to be (4x5x6), not what actually goes in the buckets.  You just need to assign values.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[][][] array = new int[4][5][6];//initializing array
    int sum=0;//define sum
    for(int[][] i: array)//start of enhanced for loop
    {
        for(int[] j: i){
            for(int k:j){ 
                sum +=k;    
            }
        }
    }//end enhanced for loop

    System.out.println("Output is " + sum);//output sum
```

The print should be outside the main loop.
In the sum = ,k is not an arry, it's an int.